# Prompting the user for 10 inputs, sotring it in an array, finding the average, and printing numbers less than average

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, average

The title is the question in mind.

Here is what I have so far:

```
html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
 </head>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
 var i;
var elmt = nums[10];
var ask = prompt("Please enter 10 numbers");
var sum = 0
for(var i =0, i< elmt.length; i++;):
    sum += parseInt(elmt[i], 10);

var avg = sum/elmt.length;

 document.write("The sum of all the elements is: " + sum + " The average is: " +avg);

 <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing to be honest. I tried researching arrays and this questions and similar ones so I can try to learn the syntax but to no avail. I'm practicing this on my own to try and learn. Please don't bash, I'm not asking anyone to do this FOR me, hints would be ok. I'm not some teenager endlessly dumping in code and hoping the internet does my homework.

EDIT1:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> nums </title>
 </head>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
var sum =0;
var belowAvg = 0;
var num = new Array(10);
var sum = 0
var i;

for(i = 0; i<10; i++;):
{
    num[i] = eval(prompt("Enter a number"));
    sum = sum + num[i];
}

avg = sum/10;
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    if ( num[i] < avg)
    {
        belowAvg++;
    }
}

alert ("average is" + avg);
alert (belowAvg + "numbers are less than the average");

</script>

 <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

EDIT2:

Ok, now I'm extremely lost. Everyone had good answers and all but my understanding isn't enough to apply any of them unfortunately. I've been playing around with all suggestions and I'm still lost. Can anyone show me an example maybe? I didn't want my hand to be held, but....

Comment: Do the inputs have to be `prompt`s? You could dump 10 `<input>` boxes on the page and react to a button press. Otherwise, you could also prompt once (accepting a comma-separated list) then use `String.prototype.split` to get them in to an array. from there, iterate over them as you have and return the result.

Comment: I guess you want to use split in order to put the ask value into elmt.

Comment: Try tackling this one piece at a time.  How do you prompt the user for input?  How do you store that input in an array?  How do you find the average of an array of numbers?  How do you iterate through an array and print the items that are less then the average?

Comment: You're not prompting 10 times. Start with an empty array `var elmts = [];` and then assign the values in a loop.

Comment: I'm updating the original post with new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but you're only prompting once and placing the input in to a variable. You need to prompt 10 times if you want 10 numbers (otherwise you need to parse the input and extract 10 numbers from it).

Assuming you wanted a few methods of populating `elmt` through `ask` (here i use `input` instead of `ask` and `nums` instead of `elmt`--but we're talking minor semantics):

Method one, prompt 10 times:

```
// initialize array with 10 elements
var nums = new Array(10);
// iterate over each element and prompt for value
for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
  var input = prompt('Enter number ' + (i + 1) + ' of ' + (nums.length + 1));
  // place value (as a number) into the array
  nums[i] = new Number(input);
}
/* sum/average code */
```

Method two, prompt once and [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
// initialize array with 10 elements
var nums = new Array(10);
// prompt for 10 numbers
var input = prompt('Enter ' + (nums.length + 1) + ' numbers separated by commas:');
var values = input.split(',');
// check we have the right amount
if (values.length == nums.length){
  // iterate over the values
  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    // place the input (as a number) into the array
    nums[i] = new Number(values[i]);
  }
}
/* sum/average code */
```

Method three, input boxes:

```
<script>
  function average(){
    // initialize array with 10 elements
    var nums = new Array(10);
    // iterate over the elements
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
      // grab <input> based on id attribute
      var input = document.getElementById('num' + i);
      // insert the value (cast as a number) in to the array
      nums[i] = new Number(input.value); // case to number
    }
    /* sum/average code */
  }
</script>

<p>Enter 10 numbers:</p>
<input type="text" id="num0" />
<input type="text" id="num1" />
<input type="text" id="num2" />
<input type="text" id="num3" />
<input type="text" id="num4" />
<input type="text" id="num5" />
<input type="text" id="num6" />
<input type="text" id="num7" />
<input type="text" id="num8" />
<input type="text" id="num9" />

<button onclick="average()">Click to average</button>
```

Comment: I didn't try this yet, but I did update my code in an edit if you don't mind taking a look.

Comment: Just did. 1: *never* use `eval()`. that can get you in trouble more times than not, and 99% of the time it's not necessary. 2: If you want to output the numbers below the average, use another array and [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the values in (then output them when you're done).

Comment: aaaaaaaaand now I'm lost -_-

Comment: Can you help me a bit further? I thought I would understand this and I just got a little more lost. I thought editing my post would bump it but I guess no one sees this in the abyss of remedial questions. I've been trying to get my code in the first edit and I'm not really sure how to get another array. I want to count the numbers that are less than the average so my final print is something like "average is X, and there are Y numbers below the average". Any more guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: @user3543981: Will put together an example, give me a minute.

Comment: @user3543981: http://jsfiddle.net/td5gr/ (not _exactly_ what you're after, but wanted to vary enough to make you think about how you'd implement it)

Comment: @user3543981: not a problem. ;-)